# Tkinter UI is blocked while downloading file

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-requests

I write some code in python to download a file but when the code is downloading the file I can't update the UI. Below is code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, Button, Label, Frame
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
from datetime import timedelta,datetime
import sys
import requests
import urllib
from socket import timeout
from threading import Thread

    
class App():
    # declare the window
    urls = []
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        
    
        # set window title
        self.window.title("Downloader")
        # set window width and height
        self.window.configure(width=500, height=300)
        self.window.minsize(500, 300)
        # set window background color
        self.window.configure(bg='lightgray')
        self.window.configure(background="white")
        
        self.frame = Frame(self.window)
        url_label = Label(self.frame, text = "Enter URL")
        url_label.pack_configure(side="left", anchor="center", fill="x", expand=0)
        
        self.urlEntry = tk.Entry(self.frame)
        self.urlEntry.pack_configure(side="left", anchor="center", fill="x", expand=1)
        
        
        self.frame.pack_configure(side="top", fill="x",anchor="center", expand=1)
        url_label.pack()
        self.urlEntry.pack()
        self.frame.pack()
          
        
        # Add Button and Label
        download_button = Button(self.window, text = "Start Download",
               command = self.startDownload)
        
        download_button.pack(side="top", anchor="nw", fill="x", expand=1)
        
          
        self.date = Label(self.window, text = "")
        self.date.pack(side="top", anchor="nw", fill="x", expand=1)
        
        
        self.console = ScrolledText(self.window,relief="solid",wrap = tk.WORD)
        self.console.configure(font='TkFixedFont', background="gray")
        self.console.configure(state="disabled")
        self.console.pack(side="top",padx=10, pady=10, fill="x", expand=1)        
        
        self.console.configure(state="disabled")
        self.window.mainloop()
        
        
    def writeLog(self, text):
        self.console.configure(state="normal")
        self.console.insert(tk.INSERT,text+"\n")
        self.console.configure(state="disabled")
        
        
    def startDownload(self):
        self.url = self.urlEntry.get()
        self.urls.append(self.url)
        threads=list()
        for url in self.urls:
            self.writeLog(datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S :- ")+"Downloading "+url)
            print(url)
#             self.writeLog(url)
            firstpos=url.rfind("/")
            lastpos=len(url)
            filename = url[firstpos+1:lastpos]
            t = Thread(target=self.downloadFile, args=(url, filename,))
            t.start()
            threads.append(t)
            
        for thread in threads:
            thread.join()
    
    
    def downloadFile(self, url, filename):
        isFileExist = self.fileExist(url)
        if isFileExist:
            with open(filename, "wb") as f:
                print("Downloading %s" % filename)
#                 self.writeLog( "Downloading %s" % filename)
                response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
                total_length = response.headers.get('content-length')
                print(total_length)
                  
                if total_length is None: # no content length header
#                     f.write(response.content)
                    print("No File:"+url)
                else:
                    dl = 0
                    total_length = int(total_length)
                    for data in response.iter_content(chunk_size=4096):
                        dl += len(data)
                        f.write(data)
                        done = int(50 * dl / total_length)
                        sys.stdout.write("\r[Downloading %s :%s%s]" % (filename, '=' * done, ' ' * (50-done)) )    
                        sys.stdout.flush()
                        if done == 50 :
                            self.writeLog(datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S :- ")+filename+" Download completed  ")
                f.close()
    
    def fileExist(self, url):
        try:
            response = urllib.request.urlopen(url,timeout=5)
            status_code = response.getcode()
            if status_code == 200:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        except urllib.request.HTTPError:
            return False
        except timeout:
            return False
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    App()
```

Please let know what is wrong with the code

Comment: Try removing the `for thread in threads: thread.join()`. That just waits for the threads to end. The threads end when the files are downloaded and until then tkinter can't update itself because you are blocking the `.mainloop()`

Comment: I added thread because I thought it will fix it problem is not fixed even after using thread

Comment: There is no point to having the `for thread in threads: thread.join()`. The only thing it does is wait for your file to download. While it is doing that, tkinter can't update itself. Try removing it and see if the issue is solved.